# MediaRecorder get Timestamps while recording

Tags: android, timestamp, android-mediarecorder

In my application I am recording video using `MediaRecorder`. Is there a way how I can count up a timestamp (as precise as possible) durring recording a video. I need this timestamp in order to synchronize some data with the recorded video afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the timestamp by calling to:

`Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()`

Just call it after you call `start()`.

Comment: Will this provide me a more or less exact timestamp when the actual recording starts?

Comment: more or less is the right definition, the difference should be in millisecond

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get timestamp from SurfaceTextur [getTimestamp()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html#getTimestamp()).

The base time (zero point) will be set by the source who is updating SurfaceTexture using updateTexImage(). I assume for you it will be camera.