# How can I get the most exact timestamp of when the audio recording actually starts when using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, timestamp, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

I am making an android app that records audio from a bluetooth earpiece. Everything works fine and the app is able to record audio through the earpiece.

However I will need the exact (or very close to exact) millisecond of when the first audio signal was recorded, if the audio recordings are going to be useful to me. I tried getting the timestamp with `System.currentTimeMillis();` right after calling `.start()` on the MediaRecorder, as mentioned [in this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502238/mediarecorder-get-timestamps-while-recording).

Sadly when I use this method for getting the start time of my audio recording it is often off by quite a lot (100ms or more even).

By getting the time befor calling `MediaRecorder.start()` and after the call, like this:

```
audioStartTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
recorder.start();
audioStartTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

I'm able to see that between `audioStartTime1` and `audioStartTime2` anywhere between 50ms to 150ms elapse. It seems like starting the MediaRecorder takes quite some time. This would be no problem at all if the recording started right after `recorder.start()` returns, however the recording doesn't start right after `recorder.start()` has returned, but still takes some time until the bluetooth earpiece really starts recording. This delay is different every time and can be more than 100ms.

Is there some kind of way for me to get a more exact timestamp for the first audio sample?

Maybe store the time of when the MediaRecorder gets the first data packet over bluetooth. How would I do that though?

[This person here also has a similar problem for video recording and did not get any useful answeres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386663/android-detecting-real-recording-mediarecorder-has-delay)

I would really appriciate some Help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a post-processing library to check for when sound is actually detected in your recording?  If the first 100-150ms of the file is silent, and then the file begins to include some non-zero decible value, you could in theory trim the head off every file to delete this silence.

Comment: @tgmerritt I do infact have silence at the beginning of all my audiofiles. The silence however is alway about 50ms long. Does the silcence mean that the MediaRecorder does afterall start recording immediatly after `.start()` called but simply records silence as long as nothing is received from the bluetooth earpiece?

Comment: I can only speculate on that part - but I think that the problem you're trying to solve is probably more easily solved after you have a recorded file than trying to time everything in real-time.  Post-production works wonders to clean up both audio and video :)

Comment: did you ever figure out how to find the exact time? @ChocolatNugget

Comment: @tonder Sadly not. Still interested in any suggestions someone might have.

Comment: @ChocolatNugget ah this is annoying. in IOS, I am able to get the exact time using AVAudioRecorder. Just because of this issue, I am not able to develop the android version of my app.